# How to recovery cluster when all nodes down?

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

If all nodes in a 3-nodes Percona Cluster have shutdown (gracefully shutdown or crash), from [this blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/01/galera-replication-how-to-recover-a-pxc-cluster/), it says that when the nodes could reach each other, the cluster could recover automatically. However, starting the nodes in such a situation seems a difficult task.

So is there a reliable and operable method to do cluster recovery in this situation?

Comment: Could you update this with version and operating system info or is the question deliberately generic? There is quite a lot more information available on the Percona website such as at this page [link](https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/13709-disaster-recovery-techniques-for-xtradb-cluster) but there may be dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the `grastate.dat` file on all 3 nodes. Which node has the highest sequence number? You should bootstrap that node. Wait for it to come online. Then start node2. It should IST from the bootstrap node. Then start node3.

Golden rule: You must always bootstrap the very first node of any cluster. Bootstrapping does not erase data; it only starts a new cluster.

Depending on the version, you may need to set `safe_to_bootstrap` in the grastate file to 1 manually.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try to check which is most advanced node 
run below command on every node and check which node has largest committed transaction value.

`mysqld_safe --wsrep-recover`

start First node which has max committed value then second and third